# How to get image url from Yahoo weather forecast XML document?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsxmlparser, yahoo-weather-api

I'm getting weather information from [yahoo weather](http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=28366761) and i'm able to parse temperature info from document but having problem to fetch image url from `<escription>` element i.e.

```
<description>
<![CDATA[
<img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/28.gif"/><br /> <b>Current Conditions:</b><br /> Mostly Cloudy, 61 F<BR /> <BR /><b>Forecast:</b><BR /> Thu - Showers. High: 66 Low: 48<br /> Fri - AM Light Rain. High: 52 Low: 37<br /> Sat - Partly Cloudy. High: 61 Low: 47<br /> Sun - AM Clouds/PM Sun. High
]]>
<![CDATA[
: 66 Low: 48<br /> Mon - PM Showers. High: 62 Low: 50<br /> <br /> <a href="http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Hakuba_Station__JP/*http://weather.yahoo.com/forecast/JAXX0105_f.html">Full Forecast at Yahoo! Weather</a><BR/><BR/> (provided by <a href="http://www.weather.com" >The Weather Channel</a>)<br/>
]]>
</description>
```

Please not that i'm using `NSXMLParser` for parsing the MXL document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @haras.prasad answer i solved this problem using `NSXMLParser` delegate and `NSRegularExpression`

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCDATA:(NSData *)CDATABlock {
    NSString *cdataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:CDATABlock encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    // Do extraction of image src here
    NSError* error;
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(<img\\s[\\s\\S]*?src\\s*?=\\s*?['\"](.*?)['\"][\\s\\S]*?>)+?"
                                                                           options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                             error:&error];

    NSString *imageUrlString = nil;
    NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:cdataString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [cdataString length])];
    if (match)
    {
        imageUrlString = [cdataString substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:2]];

        self.iconUrl = imageUrlString;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your NSXMLParserDelegate, you can call the delegate method `foundCDATA` and handle the data there.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCDATA:(NSData *)CDATABlock {
      NSString *cdataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:CDATABlock encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
      // Do extraction of image src here
}
```

You can check the documentation for the delegate method here: [NSXMLParserDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSXMLParserDelegate/parser:foundCDATA:)

Comment: do i need to parse html to get img src? If yes could you please give me some reference on how to do that?

Comment: Do you still need a parser method?

Answer (score 0):

You can get CDATA string :

```
NSString *prefix = @"<![CDATA[";
if ([xmlString hasPrefix:prefix]) {
    NSString *cdataString = [_factString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange((prefix.length+1), xmlString.length - 3 -(prefix.length+1))];
    // Do stuff with CDATA here...
    NSLog(@"%@", cdataString);
}
```